# Data cloning Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

I have a user_infos table where I store my users' information like their name, profile picture, and so on.

And I have a front-end app running where users can create posts and comment on them.

The issue is that after a user creates multiple posts and/or comments, if he changes his profile picture or name, I haven't found an optimal way to update his information in all his posts and comments simutaneously.

I know that an easy way to do this is by creating cassandra materialized views, but I was wondering if there are substitutes for this method since it is highly energy-consuming.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you create your data model. Is the user profile and the user posts in two different tables?

Comment: @RajibDeb is we use two different table

Comment: Will you be able to share the schema definition of the table. Because if you are using lets say userid as your partition key in both tables. If the profile picture and name changes in the profile table, then it should automatically reflect in the other table